# Creating Google Aggregate Rating tags With Angular 4?

Tags: angular, schema.org, google-rich-snippets, rich-snippets

I created a web site with Angular 4 and .Net WebApi
I set `Google Aggregate Rating` tags for it with Angular as the following:

```
<div class="hidden" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscopeitemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
  Rated <span itemprop="ratingValue">4.85</span>/5 based on <span  itemprop="reviewCount">207</span> 
</div>
```

When the web site is coming, Angular get ratings data from web api and show it in HTML page, so at initial HTML `Aggregate Rating` tags are not exist. So `Aggregate Rating` now work correctly.

The web site:
http://youtube.2tera.com/

How can I create `Google Aggregate Rating` tags with Angular to work correctly?

Comment: Perhaps angular-universal is what you need

Comment: What's angular-universal?

Comment: https://universal.angular.io/ `Optimized for Search Engines`